# What is the Property for textcolor and hint colour when use Stripe Library Android

Tags: android

My background is white and I want to set hintcolor as black when use below Widget.How can i Do this? Any help ??

```
<com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget
    android:id="@+id/card_input_widget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    stripe:cardTint="@color/purple"
    stripe:cardTextErrorColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>
```